# jquery horizontal menu with vertical sub menu

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, accordion, slidetoggle

I'm using jQuery code to display a vertical sub-menu when clicking on an item from my horizontal menu.

My jQuery code works fine, but when clicking on a top level menu item, I want my top level menu to stay inline, instead of breaking like is the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cQjBy/1/

And I also want the sub-menu to be right under the top menu item, with full with and grey background.

It's fine for me that the content slides when the sub menu displays, that's the effect I want to keep.

Here are 2 images of what I'm trying to achieve :

[image]

[image]

Here is my html :

```
        <header id="header">
            <ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">MENU 1</a></li>
        <ul class="sous_menu">
                <li><a href="#chateau">SUB MENU 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#rehabilitation">SUB MENU 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#espaces">SUB MENU 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#equipe">SUB MENU 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#partenaires">SUB MENU 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#privatiser">SUB MENU 6</a></li>
            </ul>
<li><a href="#">MENU 2</a></li>
        <ul class="sous_menu">
                <li><a href="#a_propos">SUB MENU 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#les_porteurs">SUB MENU 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#le_lab">SUB MENU 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#soutenir_le_projet">SUB MENU 4</a></li>
            </ul>
<li><a href="#">MENU 3</a></li>
        <ul class="sous_menu">
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU 4</a></li>
            </ul>
<li><a href="#">MENU 4</a></li>
            <ul class="sous_menu">
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU 3</a></li>
            </ul>
<li><a href="#">MENU 5</a></li>
            <ul class="sous_menu">
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU 5</a></li>
            </ul>
<li><a href="#">MENU 6</a></li>
             <ul class="sous_menu">
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU 5</a></li>
            </ul>
</ul>
</header>
<div class="content">THIS IS THE CONTENT</div>
```

My css :

```
header {
    font-size: 0px;
    top:0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    width:100%;
}

header #menu {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
header #menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid #00F800;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 80px;
}

header #menu li a {
    color: #00F800;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

header #menu .sous_menu {width:100%;background-color:lightgrey}
header #menu .sous_menu  li{
    display:block; 
    border-right: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 20px;

}
header #menu .sous_menu  li a{}

.content{margin-top:40px}
```

And my jQuery:

```
$("ul.sous_menu").hide(); /*hides the submenus*/
$("#menu li").click(function() {
    $(this).next("ul.sous_menu").slideToggle('xfast') /*opens the child submenu*/
    .siblings('ul.sous_menu:visible').slideUp('xfast'); /*closes any opened ones*/
});
```

Hope you understand my english !

thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You had to nest the sub-menus into the menus. You could have avoided many headaches:

Nest your sub-menus **HTML**

```
<li><a href="#">MENU 1</a> <!-- Starts here -->
        <ul class="sous_menu"> <!-- This is nested within --!>
                <li><a href="#chateau">SUB MENU 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#rehabilitation">SUB MENU 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#espaces">SUB MENU 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#equipe">SUB MENU 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#partenaires">SUB MENU 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#privatiser">SUB MENU 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>   <!-- Ends here -->
```

Accommodate your JQuery to handle the new structure:

```
 $("ul.sous_menu").hide(); /*hides the submenus*/
$("#menu li").click(function () {

    $(this).siblings().children('ul.sous_menu:visible').slideUp('xfast');
    $(this).children("ul.sous_menu").slideToggle('xfast') 

});
```

And add some more **CSS** to make sure the sub-menus appear under their parents :

```
width:150px;background-color:lightgrey;
position:absolute;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cQjBy/11/)**

Comment: p.s. I updated my answer. There was a small issue with the jquery

Comment: thanks for your reply. but that's not what I'm trying to do. 2 issues : 1st : when clicking on a link from a sub menus, it close the sub menu, the link is not working. 2nd : When sub menu appears, I want to keep the effect to the div after, I want the menu to push the content under, and not to be displayed over the content... the same effect as in my jsfiddle, do you see what I mean ? like in this example http://mute.com/, the header left menu... can you help me with this ?